# Can't create partitions on installation

Tags: 12.04, installation

Attaching a couple of screenshots to better explain.

[image: install]

[image: gparted]

So in the 1st screen, I can't click anything. New partition table is disabled, so are the rest of the buttons. Clicking install, results in an error.

In the 2nd screen you can see that I don't have any option to set a mount point for my newly created partition. Also if I use GParted to create my partitions, the installer doesn't see any of them.

Any ideas how I can install Ubuntu? I had no problems installing it on a different machine. Also I think the HDD was running a windows before without any problems.

Updated the questions with the result of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000914db

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  1953523711   976760832   83  Linux
```

Comment: have you run the GParted operations that you have added (in this case creating the primary partition)? Looking at your screenshot it seems as if you forgot that, because it's still pending.

Comment: The screen is just an example, I've commited the changes. Even used fdisk and still nothing.

Comment: "used fdisk" - what exactly did you do? What gives `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: I know this sounds redundant, but can't you now select `/dev/sda1` in the first screen?

Comment: Nope, still no partitions in the installer and buttons are disabled. I'm really out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had even tried to install Windows, which had no problem, but I still couldn't install Ubuntu after that.

The solution was to run `mke2fs` with some params (my colleagues ran it so I'm not sure what the params are).

Answer (score 1):

press ctrl + alt + t together to open a new terminal then type

> *sudo gparted*

if you get an error then simply type

> sudo apt-get install gparted

then follow the first command, do you partititon with gparted then select other option in ubiquity installer then install like nothing happened.