# Ubuntu Installation: Can't Create Partition on USB Stick

Tags: partitioning, usb

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 in a USB Stick. However, it seems I cannot make any partition in this stick. I have attached an image. 
[Picture: 'New Partition Table' is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6vtF.png)

Now I tried to look for other options, like: [Can't create partitions on installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277153/cant-create-partitions-on-installation), but `mke2fs` did not do any good or I did not use it properly.

Also, looked into this: [Why can't I create a partition table on my USB flash drive using GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12284/why-cant-i-create-a-partition-table-on-my-usb-flash-drive-using-gparted), but `palimpsest` is not available.

Any kind of help to create/put a boot loader, root and swap partition on same usb stick would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have tried clicking on the second line of /dev/sde (that has a partition type listed)? Did you install the driver that's apparently [available](http://linux-drivers.net/index.php?p=flashdisk&s=transcend&j=Transcend%20%28TS128GJF790K%29%20JetFlash%20790%20USB3.0%20Flash%20Drive%20128Gb%20%28RTL%29)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `gparted` couldn't format the drive, neither it could create new partition table. However, deleting the stick in `gparted` does a successful operation. Then, partition can be made during installation. Pretty spooky.

Nevertheless, the problem is solved this way. ^_^